# Strange "half to even" rounding in different languages

Tags: c, ruby, perl, bash, haskell

GNU bash, version 4.2.24:

```
$> printf "%.0f, %.0f\n" 48.5 49.5
48, 50
```

Ruby 1.8.7

```
> printf( "%.0f, %.0f\n", 48.5, 49.5 )
48, 50
```

Perl 5.12.4

```
$> perl -e 'printf( "%.0f, %.0f\n", 48.5, 49.5 )'
48, 50
```

gcc 4.5.3:

```
> printf( "%.0f, %.0f\n", 48.5, 49.5 );
48, 50
```

GHC, version 7.0.4:

```
> printf "%.0f, %.0f\n" 48.5 49.5
49, 50
```

---

Wikipedia says that this kind of rounding is called [*round half to even*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even):

> This is the default rounding mode used in IEEE 754 computing functions and operators.

Why is this rounding used by default in C, Perl, Ruby and bash, but not in Haskell?

Is it some sort of tradition or standard? And if it is a standard, why it's used by those languages and not used by Haskell? What is a point of rounding half to even?

Comment: I think you just answered your own question.  It's part of the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: @Keith Irwin, I believe he wanted to know which standard. Why don't you post that as answer, hopefully with a relevant link?

Comment: Dmitry: Your question specifically mentions "IEEE 754". That's the standard.

Comment: try %.2f? What is more accurate? To round or to truncate?

Comment: @Gabe, one little question. How do you know that my name is `DMITRY`? My nick contains only cyrillic letters. So that's your `DMITRY` reference sounds really confusing.

Comment: I can't type Cyrillic, I'd have to copy-and-paste your name. Since your name is a link, it's difficult to select, so the easiest thing was to just type your name in English.

Comment: But how can you translite my name from cyrillic to latin? Is it displayed in latin?

Comment: The reason it's used by default is because it is the fairest rounding method. There are 9 rounding possibilities. 1,2,3,4 round down.  6,7,8,9 round up.  That leaves exactly one, 5, which goes ever other way to smooth out the bias.

Comment: Transliterating isn't hard if you know a few Cyrillic letters.

Comment: The Haskell printf should be changed to use round-to-even.

Comment: @ikegami Because it seems silly to just repeat part of the question as an answer.

Comment: @Дмитрий He can transliterate because he can read at least some of the Cyrillic alphabet.  At least some of us English-speakers can.  I took four years of Russian in high school.  I may not remember how to say much beyond "Я не понимаю по-русски", but I still know my alphabet.  Clearly, you can do the transliteration, so why assume that other people couldn't?

Comment: I've submitted a patch to Haskell's printf to get round-to-even.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
GHCi> round 48.5
48
GHCi> round 49.5
50
```

The only difference is that `printf` isn't using `round` — presumably because it has to be able to round to more than just whole integers. I don't think IEEE 754 specifies anything about how to implement `printf`-style formatting functions, just rounding, which Haskell does correctly.

It would probably be best if `printf` was consistent with `round` and other languages' implementations, but I don't think it's really a big deal.

Comment: printf-style formatting functions convert to a fixed-point decimal format. IEEE 754 recommends that conversions be made in the current rounding mode, which is nearest-even by default. Note that many languages/platforms still get this wrong as of 2012, using nearest-even for conversions regardless of the current rounding mode.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Thanks for the information! However, Haskell simply cannot comply with that recommendation, since `printf` has to be a pure function. It would have to take the rounding mode as a parameter, or operate in a context (e.g. monadic) where that information is available.

Comment: Good point. Language-agnostic standards such as IEEE 754 leave a lot of ambiguity and may be inconvenient to accommodate. Another relatively similar situation is Hoare-logic verification of imperative floating-point programs, where you would rather avoid thinking of the rounding mode as an additional part of the program's state and argument to all floating-point functions, but you have to in order to handle programs that modify it at run-time.

Answer (score 6):

"Round to even" is the default for use with IEEE 754.  Haskell should probably switch to using it in `printf` for consistency reasons.  The relevant line of code is in 
`GHC.Float`

```
f 0 (x:_)  = (if x >= b2 then 1 else 0, [])
```

So, if someone wants to fix it, they can.  As ehird points out, this would just make the `roundTo` function being used by `printf` consistent with `round` although I'm not sure what other code this change would break.

EDIT: a previous version of this answer got the location of the rounding code wrong.  The only significant difference between the two implementations is if they are hardcoded to use base 10.

Comment: I don't think that's the right line of code. `Text.Printf` works with `String`, not `Text`.

Comment: @ehird Text.Printf calls a helper function called `dfmt'` which calls another helper called `dfmt` which calls `showFFloat` from Numeric.  What it does from there is implementation dependent, and when I answered this question I thought I had traced the GHC code to the `Data.Text` module, now I need to double check.

Comment: looks like you are correct: as of GHC 7.4.1 the `roundTo` function called by `formatRealFloat` is included in that file rather than a call to `Data.Text.etc`. It does the same thing, but is base aware

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for sure, but this probably has to do with the fact that this type of rounding is commonly used in accounting functions, as this is also known as Banker's rounding.  If you look further at the Wikipedia article on rounding, you'll also notice this is default in IEEE 754, so likely Haskell isn't following that standard.

Comment: The linked Wiki article states, that "The origin of the term bankers' rounding remains more obscure. If this rounding method was ever a standard in banking, the evidence has proved extremely difficult to find. To the contrary, section 2 of the European Commission report The Introduction of the Euro and the Rounding of Currency Amounts [16] suggests that there had previously been no standard approach to rounding in banking; and it specifies that "half-way" amounts should be __rounded up__." So bankers __don't use__ banker's rounding.

Comment: @A.H. Actually, they do still use banker's rounding to a limited extent.  I can state that with knowledge, as I used to work for a banking group.

Comment: I have first hand knowledge of rounding used in financial institutions too. But not in the USA. But the audience here is international too.

Comment: @A.H. - clearly they use bankers rounding about half the time ;-)

Comment: @A.H. Always rounding up introduces a bias.  It’s a big no-no. That’s why nothing defaults to producing numerically inaccurate results. By rounding towards even, you split the difference and iron out the bias. Anybody who says to always round up is either an idiot or a crook.